# Expression result unused: strange behaviour of c++ compiler?

Tags: xcode, c++11

I accidentally typed the following code but my code successfully built and even ran properly.

```
std::string myString = "This is my string ";
std::shared_ptr<std::string> s = std::make_shared<std::string>(myString);
p->pushString(s);”accidental typo”;
```

It just showed a warning `Expression result unused`.

Why it is not a compiler or run time error?

I am using Xcode editor

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can have arbitrary expressions as statements? That's how simple functions calls works, or assignments. In fact the statement

```
p->pushString(s);
```

is actually such an expression-statement. The `p->pushString(s)` part is an expression, it's the context (with the terminating semi-colon) that turns it into a statement.

That also means you can do something like

```
5;
```

Or in your case

```
"some string here";
```

Those are valid statements. They do however produce a result, which is (legally) discarded or ignored, but might cause the compiler to emit a warning about the ignored result.

It's really no different than e.g.

```
some_function_which_returns_a_result();  // Result ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is not a compiler [...] error?

Because it does not violate any rule of the C++ standard. If a program conforms to the standard then the compiler should allow its compilation. However, it was friendly enough to warn you that the expression is useless.

> or run time error?

The expression doesn't result in any executed code, so it would be quite surprising if it resulted in a run time error.